# Wrapped InkWell with an Expanded doesn't work

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to finish my application but the onTap of the InkWell wrapped with an Expanded doesn't work, it's not a problem about the function that I call but is about the InkWell problem. How can I resolve this?

```
Expanded(
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    reset();
                  });
                },
                child: MyCard(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.07,
                  color: Color(0xfff4a261),
                  child: Text(
                    'Reset',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

This is the custom class I've created that is inside the code above

```
class MyCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color color;
  final Widget child;
 
  double height;
 
  MyCard({this.color, this.child, this.height});
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
      child: Container(
        height: this.height,
        child: FlatButton(onPressed: () {}, child: this.child),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: this.color,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Material Widget is where the Inkwell reactions are getting painted. If there are any opaque graphics in between them(For eg. painted using Container, DecorationBox etc), then the splashes won't be visible as they are painted under these widgets.

You can wrap the InkWell with a Material Widget for fixing this.

```
         Expanded(
          child: Material(
              child: InkWell(
                   onTap: () {
                   print("Clicked");
                     },
               child: MyCard(
               height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.07,
               color: Color(0xfff4a261),
                  child: Text(
                    'Reset',
                       style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                             ),
                          ),
                      ),
                    ) ,
                   );
```

Comment: Sorry but where the expanded went?

Comment: @DanielMenconi You can wrap Expanded over Inkwell. Updated the code for your reference, Thanks

Comment: It didn't work though, some problem with expanded now

Comment: @DanielMenconi It doesn't seem to be an issue with Expanded Widget. Please add additional info if you can.

Comment: Edited it, I hope it's enough, the problem is that the onTap doesn't actually work

Comment: I hope it is working now. Copied your code and tested it in my machine. Only tweak I had to do was to wrap the InkWell with Material widget. Expanded widget was given at the top of the widget tree, as shown